# pandas: issue to calculate daily summation values using groupby(index.floor('D')).sum()

Tags: dataframe, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe as `df_insitu` with a column named as `GPP_uStar_f`. I attach first two days of the dataframe as below, and want to calculate the daily summation value of the dataframe:

```
datetime
2011-01-01 02:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 05:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 06:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 07:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 08:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 10:00:00   -0.019085
2011-01-01 13:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-01 15:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-05 06:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-05 19:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-05 20:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 03:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 05:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 08:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 12:00:00   -0.024992
2011-01-06 15:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 16:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 17:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 19:00:00        -0.0
2011-01-06 21:00:00        -0.0
Name: GPP_uStar_f, dtype: object
```

If I tried with

```
df_test = df_insitu.GPP_uStar_f[(df_insitu.index.year == 2011) & (df_insitu.index.month == 1)].iloc[0:20].copy()
print(df_test.groupby(df_test.index.floor('D')).sum())
```

then I got:

```
datetime
2011-01-01   -0.019089
2011-01-05   -0.000002
2011-01-06   -0.024996
Name: GPP_uStar_f, dtype: object
```

but if I use `df_plot.GPP_uStar_f.groupby(df_plot.GPP_uStar_f.index.floor('D')).sum()`, I didn't get the value for `2011-01-01`. I got results like:

```
2011-01-01    0
2011-01-02    0
2011-01-03    0
2011-01-04    0
2011-01-05    0
2011-01-06    0
2011-01-07    0
Name: GPP_uStar_f, dtype: object
```

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Creating a sample datetime range
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2018 11:59:00', periods=20, freq='3H')

df=pd.DataFrame(rng,columns=['Datetime'])
df['val']=np.random.randint(1,50,size=20)

df.head()

Datetime                val
0   2018-01-01 11:59:00 10
1   2018-01-01 14:59:00 10
2   2018-01-01 17:59:00 21
3   2018-01-01 20:59:00 40
4   2018-01-01 23:59:00 32
```

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Datetime",freq="1D")).sum()

Datetime    val
2018-01-01  150
2018-01-02  251
2018-01-03  104
```